# Bluetooth broadcast - host name vs friendly name vs alias

Tags: bluetooth

My Raspberry Pi is configured for Bluetooth. I change the friendly name using hciconfig:

```
$ sudo hciconfig hci0 name "MyTest"
$ sudo hciconfig -a hci0
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: UART
...
UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
Name: 'MyTest'
...
```

On a different Ubuntu box, I scan for nearby devices:

```
$ sudo bluetoothctl
# scan on
...
[NEW] Device DC:A6:32:88:A6:12 raspberrypi
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:88:A6:12 Name: MyTest
[CHG] Device DC:A6:32:88:A6:12 Alias: MyTest
```

Why does it show three different items? And where is it picking the name "raspberrypi" from? Is Pi also broadcasting its host name? Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to mention is that `hciconfig` has been [deprecated](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bluetooth#Deprecated_BlueZ_tools) by the BlueZ developers in 2017 so will be removed from systems at some point in the future.

The current tool for this job is btmgmt (assuming you have an up-to-date system).

```
sudo btmgmt name MyRaspberryPi MyPi
```

In `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` there is this information:

```
# Defaults to 'BlueZ X.YZ', if Name is not set here and plugin 'hostname' is not loaded.
# The plugin 'hostname' is loaded by default and overides the Name set here so
# consider modifying /etc/machine-info with variable PRETTY_HOSTNAME=<NewName> instead.
#Name = BlueZ
```